# After changing app name signed apk not containing the updated code in Android

Tags: android

## *when i am generating normal apk file every thing is fine for me*

when i am generating signed apk file it is not updated my code changes ?
I updated it many times but after changing the app name i am facing this issue. my app in not in play store i have also my older ".jks" file.

### **I already Tried**

I also try with new ".jks" but facing the same issue.I also cleaned my project and deleted the build file but unable to find the right way.

Answer (score 1):

I found my updated Apk inside release folder, but found another apk on click of locate option (that comes after successful generating apk ) outside of release folder that apk file was not containing my update code.